# Laravel URL redirecting back

Tags: php, html, laravel, url, routes

I have this problem when using `<a href="f/{{$f->id}}">` it redirects me to the path + the current path . for example I am in

> localhost:8888/f

when I click the `<a href to e/{{$e->id}}"` it gives me

> localhost:8888/f/e/888.

Do anyone have an idea why it stores the current url ? even if I click in the menu it return the same.

Thank you

Comment: You need to add / infront of 'f'. So the link should be `<a href="/f/{{$f->id}}">`

Answer (score 3):

if

```
href="x/x" you will redirect like .com/whaevery/x/x
```

then if you change

```
href="/x/x" then you will redirect to .com/x/x
```

So you must set the base path

Comment: I know but it seems not to be working, it just adds the previous /f to the e or vis versa